# Two models for one Controller in Laravel (methods Edit & Update)

Tags: php, laravel

Would you please let me know if this controller **SerieController** is correct? As I don't think so.
There are two models in fact. One Model is **Serie** and the other is **Mark**.

When, I click on the drop down list, I don't see my items...

[image]

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $series = Serie::with('marks')->find($id);
        return view('admin.series.edit', compact('series'));
    }



    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'fk_mark' => 'required'
        ]);
    
        $series = Serie::with('marks')->find($id);
        $series->name = $request->get('name');
        $series->fk_mark = $request->get('fk_mark');
        $series->save();
        return redirect()->route('series.index')
                  ->with('success', 'updated successfully');
    }
```

My **edit.blade.php**

```
<form class="panel-body" action="{{route('series.update',$series->id)}}" method="POST">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
@csrf
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="form-group-input-1">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$series->name}}">
</fieldset>
    
<div class="form-group">
<label for="company-content">Select Mark</label>
<select name="fk_mark" id="" class="form-control">
@foreach($series->marks as $mark)
<option value="{{$mark['id']}}">{{$mark['name_mark']}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

Concerning the model

Model **Serie**

```
class Serie extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'fk_mark'];

    public function marks(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mark', 'fk_mark');
       
    }

}
```

Model **Mark**

```
class Mark extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name_mark'];
    
    public function series(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Serie', 'fk_mark');
    }

    
    public function cars(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Car','fk_serie');
   }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use the same controller for two different models?

Comment: You can name controller's methods however you want. Even, for example, `editMark` or `editSerie`. Just do not forget to bind these methods to urls in `routes/api.php` or `routes/web.php`.

Comment: @Ross Wilson: Because there is a foreign key.

Comment: what is the relationship between two models?

Comment: And also show the database structure of these tables?

Comment: @Inzamam Idrees: I have edited my first message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **edit** function you have to do this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
     $series = Serie::with('marks')->find($id);
     return view('admin.series.edit', compact('series'));
}
```

and in your **blade** you will fetch the marks like this:

```
$series->marks->name_mark;
```

and it is the same method for **update** function to update two tables data.

I hope it would helpful.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the synthax of the methode edit. Do you have an idea if the syntax of the method update is correct ? In my drop down list I don't get the items... :-( I have edited my first message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Which version of Laravel do you use?

Check out [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) which would compact your functions like this:

```
public function edit(Serie $serie)
{
    $series->load('marks');
    return view('admin.series.edit', compact('series'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Serie $serie)
{
    $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'fk_mark' => 'required'
    ]);

    $series->load('marks');

    $series->name = $request->get('name');
    $series->fk_mark = $request->get('fk_mark');
    $series->save();

    return redirect()->route('series.index')
              ->with('success', 'updated successfully');
}
```

Further tipps for debugging:

1. Set `'debug' => true` in your app.php
2. Try to use `dd($serie);` to see what happens to your model.
3. Install [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar): `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev`
4. Check your database tables to see if your code successfully created the data.
5. Write Unit/Feature [Test](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing) to validate your application logic
6. Provide more data in your next SO question like sql schema, error messages etc

Without the sql schema and exact problem you're facing it's very hard to debug someone else code. I hope this helps nonetheless.

Edits: grammar, spelling and last sentence fixed/added